# Cinnamon crashes and then I can't increase the maximum resolution

Tags: nvidia, cinnamon, resolution, display-settings, proprietary-drivers

I'm installing a new system - new hardware, old OS (well, not old; it's Linux Mint 18). My system has on-board Intel graphics (previously it was a Z77 board, now it's Z170), and a discrete GPU - that I do *not* want to use for my display; but I do need to use it for computation, so I do need nVIDIA's driver in place.

Anyway, there are multiple phases to my story, but let me cut it short:

- Before the HW upgrade, my Cinnamon would crash and load in fallback mode - which I could live with, sort of, since at least the resolution was my monitor's native one - 1920x1080.
- After the HW upgrade, I get the same crash and fallback mode - but now, for some reason, the resolution is limited to 720x400 (or even 640x480? who knows).

My questions:

- How can I get the higher resolutions back again?
- How can I get Cinnamon to (1) not crash while (2) not using nouveau and (3) having the nVIDIA kernel driver up and (4) not trying to use it?
- I have an extra, old-ish nVIDIA card lying around; will it help if I try to use that somehow, instead of the on-board graphics?

lshw -c VGA results:

```
   *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:e8000000-e9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:f2000000-f2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

contents of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 375.39  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-09)  Tue Jan 31 20:47:44 PST 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to address the "can't increase the maximum resolution" part - not Cinnamon crashing which I'll ignore in this answer (woe is me).

Anyway, it's a combination of two issues:

1. the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file, which the nVIDIA driver generates, completely ignores the presence of the Intel on-board graphics adapter, probably making X itself fall back to some always-supposed-to-work, lowest-common-denominator-of-PCs display driver (frame buffer device? Maybe). If you remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, the X server itself does some sort of auto-detection magic with all the drivers it has.

but that's not quite enough, you see, at this point you *still* get the low resolution; and while the list of available resolutions now includes all values up to 1920×1080, selecting one of them *does nothing*. Which brings us to...

2. Launch [`arandr`](http://screenshots.debian.net/package/arandr) (if it's missing, `sudo apt-get install arandr` will install it with some dependencies). In the menu bar, choose "Outputs". Now locate the outgoing video connection you're using (in my case it's HDMI 1); enter that submenu; you should see the same list of resolutions as with the Cinnamon display settings – select the natural resolution (1920×1080 in my case). Finally, on the menu bar, choose "Layout → Apply". This should actually trigger the resolution change.

Step 2 can also be taken using `lxrandr` (intended for LXDE) or the undelying `xrandr` command-line utility, for which `arandr` and `lxrandr` are front-ends.